# How can I add a second type for a template method of a template class without changing class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class

```
template <typename S>
class Foo {

   template <typename T>
   T Bar();

}
```

how can I change `Bar` so that I can use it as below without changing class template type?

```
Foo<int> f;
f.Bar<int,MyType>();
```

here, int is type of `Foo` and `MyType` is just another type to change `Bar()` behavior on top of its instance type.

This is not working as intended:

```
template <typename S>
template <typename T>
T Foo<S>::Bar()
{
    // logic with T t
}
```

but this works:

```
template <typename S>
template <typename T>
T Foo<S>::Bar(T * dummyNullPointer)
{
    // logic with T t
}
```

is there a neat version instead of below code?

```
f.Bar<int>((float *)0);
```

preferably

```
f.Bar<int,MyType>();
```

or

```
f.Bar<MyType>(); // better, but expects int for example and gives error
```

---

**Edit:** real usage is

```
void SomeClass<SomeType>::SomeMethod(SomeType1<SomeType> p)
{
      Something something = p.SomeWork<Something>(); // does not work
}
```

Comment: `f.Bar<int,MyType>()` While `int` is the type that `Bar` returns, what is `MyType` used for?

Comment: To alter sub-calculations with a different type, such as floats instead of doubles for more speed, just for sub-calculations but different than main type where it is not necessary to have more precision. Something like a strategy or dependency injection but with this one-word change.

Comment: It can't be done without changing the class template, but is that a hard requirement?

Comment: No its not a hard requirement. If I change class template, whole project needs to be changed(a uses b, b uses c, .... y uses z all with same <S> but e needs also to have a <T>)

Comment: should I use a define? `#define typeoff(x) (x*)0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specialize a member function of a non-specialised class. That's simply a language limitation.

If you're prepared to specialise the class, you can do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename S>
struct Foo {

    template <typename T>
    T Bar();

};

template <typename S>
template <typename T>
T Foo<S>::Bar()
{
    std::cout << "usual thing" << std::endl;
    return T();
}

struct MyType {};

template<> template<>
std::tuple<int, MyType> Foo<int>::Bar<std::tuple<int, MyType>>()
{
    std::cout << "my thing" << std::endl;
    return std::tuple<int, MyType> { 1, {} };
};


int main()
{
    auto f = Foo<int>();
    auto x = f.Bar<int>();
    auto y = f.Bar<std::tuple<int, MyType>>();
}
```

If not, then you'll have to have your member functions defer to function objects which can be partially specialised:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


// general case
template<class S, class T, class...Ts>
struct BarOp;

template <typename S>
struct Foo {

    template <typename...Ts>
    auto Bar() -> decltype(auto)
    {
        auto op = BarOp<Foo<S>, Ts...>();
        return op(this);
    }

};

// general case of single T
template<class S, class T>
struct BarOp<S, T>
{
    auto operator()(S* p) const
    {
        std::cout << "usual thing" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};


struct MyType {};

// now partially specialise for T, MyTyoe
template<class S, class T>
struct BarOp<S, T, MyType>
{
    auto operator()(S* p) const
    {
        std::cout << "other thing" << std::endl;
        return T(10);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto f = Foo<int>();
    auto x = f.Bar<int>();
    auto y = f.Bar<int, MyType>();
}
```

expected output:

```
usual thing
other thing
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: It can be run:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename S>
class Foo {
   /* internal use of S */
   int bar2(S s);
public:
   template <typename T, typename K>
   T Bar() {
        /* internal use of K, may be also S */
        K var = 5.3;
        return (T) var; //convert K to T
   }
};


int main() {
    Foo<int> f;
    int res = f.Bar<int, double>();
    std::cout <<"res = " << res << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "invalid declarator before `>` token" compiler responds. "Expected primary expression before `>`" is another error when tried with only T instead of T and K. Because it still expects S at first type parameter.

Comment: I've edited the answer so as to have a running example.

Comment: In my code, it is ` f.Bar<S,T>()` and it complains about "expected primary expression before `,`" where S comes from other methods and classes that use ` Foo`. I can't directly write int there.

Comment: Then, I don't understand your question. Is the template class Foo that you can't change or the template member Bar? Can you edit your question and show the use of MyType?